# Element collapses after setting navbar to position:fixed

Tags: html, css

I want my sidemenu to be fixed. But whenever I do it the content page crashes.
It's this class `menu_left` . When I remove position: fixed then all works fine. But i want it to be fixed. I just want the menu to stay in position so I can scroll down my content only.

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.13);
}


#app {
    display: flex;
}

.topbar-user {
    display: flex;
}

.menu_left {
    background: #333c4e;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}

.menu_left-icon {
    padding: 20px;
}

.menu_left-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu_left-item:hover {
    background: #293141;
    transition: 0.5s;
    
}

.topbar-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.main__content {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.main__content-container {
    padding: 34px 34px;
}

.imgs {
    width: 34px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.white-card {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 34px;
    height: auto;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.13);

}

.card1 {
    flex: 1;
}

.card2 {
    padding: 20px;

}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu_left {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>


    <nav>
        <div class="topbar-items">
       <H1>Logo</H1>
       <div class="topbar-user">
           <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
           <p>Jan Kowalski</p>
           <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
       </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

<div id="app">
   <div class="menu_left">
   <a href="" class="menu_left-item">
    <div class="menu_left-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
    <div class="menu_left-text"> Item</div>
   </a>
   <a href="" class="menu_left-item">
    <div class="menu_left-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
    <div class="menu_left-text"> Item</div>
   </a>
   </div>

   <div class="main__content">
       <div class="main__content-container">
<h2>Main Page</h2>
<div class="white-card">

<div class="card-title">
    <img src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/2-29162_notification-free-internet-website-icon-vector-linkedin-circle-logo-png.png" class="imgs">
 </div>
 <div class="card1">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <p>message</p>

 </div>
 <div class="card2">
    <p>19.02.2020</p>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="white-card">

    <div class="card-title">
        <img src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/2-29162_notification-free-internet-website-icon-vector-linkedin-circle-logo-png.png" class="imgs">
     </div>
     <div class="card1">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <p>message</p>
    
     </div>
     <div class="card2">
        <p>19.02.2020</p>
     </div>
    
    </div>

       </div>
  


   </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with you code, as you can see from your snippet - it is working perfectly. The problem must be with something else in your site, but withotu having any more information to work with, we can't tell what the problem might be. What exactly do you mean by "crashes"? Do you get an error? A blank screen?

Comment: Running the code snippet in full screen and commenting out `position: fixed;` in DevTools makes it work correctly. No crash.

Comment: When you run the code snippet you can see that the divs are under the menu. When you remove the position fixed they arent.

Comment: Pages don't crash; browsers crash. Please [edit] your question to more accurately reflect what you expect to see, and what you actually see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I undesrtand you meant to say the content "collapses" to the left (not crashes).

You could use a pusher placeholder element like so:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

nav {
    padding: 10px 40px;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.13);
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#app {
    display: flex;
    padding-top: 47px;
}

.topbar-user {
    display: flex;
}

.menu_left {
    background: #333c4e;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
}
.menu_left-pusher {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.menu_left-icon {
    padding: 20px;
}

.menu_left-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu_left-item:hover {
    background: #293141;
    transition: 0.5s;
    
}

.topbar-items {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}


.main__content {
    width: 100%;
}

.main__content-container {
    padding: 34px 34px;
}

.imgs {
    width: 34px;
    padding: 20px;
}

.white-card {
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: 34px;
    height: auto;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: 0 0.1875rem 0.375rem 0 rgba(0,0,0,.13);

}

.card1 {
    flex: 1;
}

.card2 {
    padding: 20px;

}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .menu_left {
        display: none;
    }

}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css">
</head>
<body>


    <nav>
        <div class="topbar-items">
       <H1>Logo</H1>
       <div class="topbar-user">
           <i class="fas fa-bell"></i>
           <p>Jan Kowalski</p>
           <i class="fas fa-angle-down"></i>
       </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

<div id="app">
  <div class="menu_left-pusher">...</div>
   <div class="menu_left">
   <a href="" class="menu_left-item">
    <div class="menu_left-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
    <div class="menu_left-text"> Item</div>
   </a>
   <a href="" class="menu_left-item">
    <div class="menu_left-icon"><i class="fas fa-home"></i></div>
    <div class="menu_left-text"> Item</div>
   </a>
   </div>

   <div class="main__content">
       <div class="main__content-container">
<h2>Main Page</h2>
<div class="white-card">

<div class="card-title">
    <img src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/2-29162_notification-free-internet-website-icon-vector-linkedin-circle-logo-png.png" class="imgs">
 </div>
 <div class="card1">
    <h4>User</h4>
    <p>message</p>

 </div>
 <div class="card2">
    <p>19.02.2020</p>
 </div>

</div>

<div class="white-card">

    <div class="card-title">
        <img src="https://www.clipartmax.com/png/middle/2-29162_notification-free-internet-website-icon-vector-linkedin-circle-logo-png.png" class="imgs">
     </div>
     <div class="card1">
        <h4>User</h4>
        <p>message</p>
    
     </div>
     <div class="card2">
        <p>19.02.2020</p>
     </div>
    
    </div>

       </div>
  


   </div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Scrolling down makes the top scroll as well.

Comment: It said nothing about it in your question. I edited the code to make the navbar fixed as well.

Comment: Is there no alternative to page pushing div? It looks terrible on responsive views. I do not want to adjust every resolution for that. When it wasn't fixed it looked perfect on every resolution.

Comment: You can just display:none the pusher when you hide the sidebar

Comment: The alternative would be to use fixed margins to compensate for the area where the sidebar is (like I did with the top navbar). The problem is the fixed elements gets outside the normal flow, so you have to compensate some other way, either with a pusher or with regular margins or paddings

Comment: How did you know that it had to be pushed 200px to the right?

Comment: Because that's the sidebar's width. If you sidebars width is variable you would need to use javascript, as far as I know

Comment: Please mark the answer at the left if you found it useful, and let me know if there are more doubts

Comment: What does   `flex: 0 0 200px;` do? why does `margin-right: 200xp` not gives same effect?

Comment: Anything you do to a fixed positioned element will not affect any other element of the page, it's the same with position absolute, even if you add a padding of a margin to it. "flex: 0 0 200px" is just saying to the element to be 200px width (the 3 values mean don't grow, don't shrink and be exactly 200px), you have to do it this way instead of just width:200px because the parent has display:flex

Comment: If you don-t want to use the pusher you can instead remove the width:100% from the .main__content element and add this instead: margin-left: 200px; flex-grow: 1;